# How can we use ES6 modules in Node program without "type" : "module" in package.json?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, package.json

I have a server (implemented with NodeJS), and a client (implemented using Vue, compiled with vue-cli) that share some code. The problem is that Vue does not support `"type": "module"` option, and I cannot run both programs without getting an error from one side or another.

I'm wondering: is that passobile, and how can we use ES6 modules in a NodeJS script, without specifying `"type": "module"` inside the `package.json` file ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found a workaround: using esm nodejs package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm